# Please tell me why virtual function is not working in the following code

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, virtual-functions

When i run this code , Output is as expected "This is derived 2" due to late binding because we used virtual function at the base class.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class  Base {
        public :
        virtual void show() {
            cout<<"This is base class"<<endl;
        }
    };
    class  Derived : public Base {
        public:
        void show() {
            cout<<"This is derived class"<<endl;
        }
    };

    class D2 : public Derived {
        public :
        void show () {
            cout<<"This is derived 2"<<endl;
        }
    };

    int main() {
        Base *obj = new D2();
        obj->show();
        return 0;
    }
```

Similarly, if i change the code to

```
        #include <iostream>
        using namespace std;

        class  Base {
            public :
             void show() {
                cout<<"This is base class"<<endl;
            }
        };
        class  Derived : public Base {
            public:
            virtual void show() {
                cout<<"This is derived class"<<endl;
            }
        };

        class D2 : public Derived {
            public :
            void show () {
                cout<<"This is derived 2"<<endl;
            }
        };

        int main() {
            // your code goes here
            Derived *obj = new D2();
            obj->show();
            return 0;
        }
```

Same thing happens, virtual function is defined in the base class which in this case is "Derived" class and Pointer is also of the type "Derived" so again calling show() gives me the most derived version.

But i can't understand what is happening when virtual function is defined in the "Derived" class and i use the base pointer of the class "Base". The output of the following code

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class  Base {
        public :
         void show() {
            cout<<"This is base class"<<endl;
        }
    };
    class  Derived : public Base {
        public:
        virtual void show() {
            cout<<"This is derived class"<<endl;
        }
    };

    class D2 : public Derived {
        public :
        void show () {
            cout<<"This is derived 2"<<endl;
        }
    };

    int main() {
        // your code goes here
        Base *obj = new D2();
        obj->show();
        return 0;
    }
```

Output : "This is base class". Please help me understand this output.

Comment: You have a base class pointer, in the base class `show` is not virtual. So of course it's calling the base class one.

Comment: @Borgleader Yes, but i have defined the virtual function in Derived class and D2 is derived from Derived. Shouldn't it call show from D2 ?

Comment: No because the static type of the pointer is Base and in base the function is not virtual so it knows it can resolve the call at compile time, the runtime type of the object pointed to by the pointer does not matter.

Comment: It's not really clear what your problem/question is. The output is exactly what one would expect. Perhaps you should read up on how `virtual` functions and polymorphism work. You cannot inherit in the base from the derived. The `virtual` function doesn't override a matching `virtual` function in the base and only affects usage from a `Derived*`.

Answer (score 5):

The reason your last snippet does not work is that the `void show()` function is `virtual` in your derived class only, but not in the base class. If any of the classes derived from `Derived` would override it, and then you call it through a pointer to `Derived`, you would see polymorphic behavior. The way you did it, however, the call through the base pointer is non-virtual, hence it is dispatched to the `Base`'s implementation.

You can fix this by declaring `show` virtual in the base class:

```
class  Base {
    public :
    virtual void show() {
//  ^^^^^^^
        cout<<"This is base class"<<endl;
    }
};
```

[Demo 1](http://ideone.com/l2I3x8)

or by accessing `D2` through a pointer to `Derived`:

```
Derived *obj = new D2();
obj->show();
```

[Demo 2](http://ideone.com/O3dLlV)

Answer (score 0):

In your final example, `D2` is a `Base*`, so whether or not that class gets derived doesn't matter.

If you had made `obj` a pointer to `Derived` or `D2`, the results would be different.

Answer (score 0):

The static type of object `obj` is `Base *`

```
Base *obj = new D2();
```

So the compiler can call only member functions declared in this class. In class Base function `show` is not virtual. So it was selected by the compiler at compilation time. Base class knows nothing about virtual functions declared in derived classses. In your example the base class even does not have a table of addresses of virtual functions because neither function in the class declared as virtual.

That a virtual function of a derived class would be called the derived class shall to substitute the address of the base class virtual function for the address of its own function in the table of addresses of virtual functions in the base class.